# Detecting Characters in an XSLT

Tags: xslt, character-encoding, special-characters, mojibake

I have encountered some odd characters that do not display properly in Internet Explorer, such as these: â€œ, â€“, and â€™. I think they're carried over from copy-and-paste Word content.

I am using XSLT to build the page content and it would be great to detect these characters in the XSLT and replace them with valid HTML codes. I already do string replacement in the style sheet, but I'm not sure how detect these encoded characters or whether it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about simply changing the encoding for the Stylesheet as well as its output to UTF-8? The characters you mention are `“`, `–` and `’`. Certainly not invalid or so, given the correct encoding (the characters are at least perfectly valid in Codepage 1252).

Answer (score 0):

Using a good XML editor such as [XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/products/xmlspy/xml_editor.html) should highlight any errors in formatting your XSLT by validating at development time.

Answer (score 0):

Jeni Tennison's [Multiple string replacements](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/StringReplace.html) may be a good starting point.